# Is there a word or idioms for "political necessity"?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Is there a word or idioms for "political necessity"? For example, let's say politicians need to do something or enact a policy no matter how unpopular it is, because of a political necessity. What do you call them? Is there a word? If not, is there an idiom that express this idea directly or indirectly? If so, how so?

Comment: "Is there a word for" questions should contain either "The work in my native language is ...." but the dictionary translates this as ..... and I don't think that is good translation because...."   OR  "The reason I think the word should exist in English is ...."    For example, what is wrong with "Political necessity"?